# Join / merge two Python SimpleNamespace

Tags: python, types

Simple question: How do I merge Python's SimpleNamespace?

It looks like there is no way to do this in a simple command like `a.update(b)` or `a | b`. In fact, I haven't even found a way to systematically access all attributes of a SimpleNamespace.

Any leads?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each `SimpleNamespace` has a `__dict__` slot, which gives access to its actual attributes. `**`-unpacking the `__dict__` from multiple `SimpleNamespace`s into a new `SimpleNamespace` effectively merges them.

```py
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> first = SimpleNamespace(a=0, b=1, c=2)
>>> second = SimpleNamespace(x=0, y=1, z=2)
>>> SimpleNamespace(**first.__dict__, **second.__dict__)
namespace(a=0, b=1, c=2, x=0, y=1, z=2)
```

Note that it is a `TypeError` to merge namespaces with overlapping attributes this way.

To merge namespaces with possibly overlapping keys, use an intermediate dictionary and unpack it again (`**{...}`). The values of later namespaces take precedence with this scheme.

```
>>> first = SimpleNamespace(a=0, b=1, c=2)
>>> second = SimpleNamespace(c=0, d=1, e=2)
>>> SimpleNamespace(**{**first.__dict__, **second.__dict__})
namespace(a=0, b=1, c=0, d=1, e=2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Building on that, I prevented the `TypeError` by first building the dict: `args_dict = {**vars(existing_args), **vars(args)}     args = SimpleNamespace(**args_dict)`